# How to make code with many little differ if-s shorter?

Tags: javascript

How I can make this code shorter ? Especially code part with if-s
This is code for checking how much bombs are near every 'not border' element in minesweeper game.

```
for(let i = 1; i < height-1; i++){
    for(let j = 1; j < width-1; j++){
      if(tdGet[i*width+j].classList != "bomb"){
        let bombNear = 0;
        if(tdGet[i*width+j+1].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(tdGet[i*width+j-1].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(tdGet[i*width+j+width].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(tdGet[i*width+j-width].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(tdGet[i*width+j+width+1].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(tdGet[i*width+j-width+1].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(tdGet[i*width+j+width-1].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(tdGet[i*width+j-width-1].classList == "bomb"){bombNear++}
        if(bombNear != 0){
          tdGet[i*width+j].classList.add("bombNear" + bombNear);
        }
        else{
          tdGet[i*width+j].classList.add("noBomb");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use another two nested loops to iterate over the 8 surrounding cells (ignoring the current cell)

Comment: This question should really be on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is for working code and discussions of how to improve it. Stack Overflow is for solving problems with non-working code. Post it there and I (along with others) would be happy to comment)

Comment: `classList.contains("bomb")` is more elegant. Even better would be having a model of your minefield in memory, e.g. as an array, and separate the presentation / view / css from your model.

Comment: Why aren't you testing the pieces at the edge, or are they just a padding "buffer" region around the outside to simplify your logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways in which you could do this. One way would be to store the different offsets in an array like so:

```
offsets = [1, -1, width, -width, width+1, -width+1, width-1, -width-1];
```

And in the double for-loop replace the ifs with:

```
for (offset in offsets) {
  var index = i*width+j+offset;
  if (index >= 0 && index < tdGet.length && tdGet[index].classList=="bomb") {
     bombNear++;
  }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to check that the resulting offset legally falls within the `tdGet` array

Comment: Fair enough, though in all fairness the original code didn't do that either :)

Comment: it sort of does - it only iterates the inner elements of the matrix and not the edges, although that doesn't match the usual rules.

Comment: assuming that the OP's failure to iterate over the edge pieces was a mistake, the remaining problem with your bounds test is that it could cause wrapping, i.e comparing a piece on the right hand edge would wrap onto the left edge.